# Graphic driver for HP Elitebook 840 g1

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel-graphics, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my HP Elitebook 840 g1, and I need to install a graphics driver.

- Intel® Core™ i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- OS type: 64-bit

Where I can find the correct graphics driver for my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers for Intel Graphics are already included.

Do NOT install anything else.

Comment: Thanks. But I got some problems such as the screen got black for some seconds and even stay like this. Is not it a driver problem?